What is the significance of vssps in some Azure DevOps rest API instances
I'm having some challenges performing a Get on the ADO Identities service:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/ims/identities/read-identities?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1&tabs=HTTP
One thing I noticed is that while most URIs show the instance as:
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}
Identities precedes the instance with vssps:
https://vssps.dev.azure.com/{organization}
What is the meaning of vssps? Is there documentation for this anywhere? What are the implications when this is encountered? If I'm calling the API with az devops invoke do I include vssps in the org parameter?


What is the meaning of vssps? Is there documentation for this anywhere?

VSSPS in Azure DevOps means Visual Studio Shared Platform Services. SPS is a core set of services, such as identity, account, and profile, that are used by every service in Azure DevOps.
Here is the official blog about the vssps definition: How to add licensed users to VS Team Services via the API
When this vssps flag is present in Azure DevOps Rest API, it means that the Rest API is related to identity, account, and profile.

If I'm calling the API with az devops invoke do I include vssps in the org parameter?

Refer to this doc about: az devops invoke

--org --organization


Azure DevOps organization URL. You can configure the default organization using az devops configure -d organization=ORG_URL. Required if not configured as default or picked up via git config. Example: https://dev.azure.com/MyOrganizationName/.

When you use az devops invoke Cli, you don't need to include vssps in org parameters.
